# htaccess not updating on the server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm at a bit of a loss. I'm working on a website so I have created a temporary `construction.html` page that I want to redirect all IPs to other than my own. Here is what my `.htaccess` looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R,L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.org/construction.html

Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.34\.567\.891
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/construction.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /construction.html [R=302,L]
```

1. What's strange is that it seemed to work initially, but my IP still gets rejected **most of the time**, but I haven't found a pattern. Sometimes I can access the root `index.html` if I explicitly navigate to it.
2. What's even stranger is that if I comment out those last four lines, I still get redirected to the `construction.html` page.

I've made sure to clear the cache of the browser, and that doesn't seem to do anything. Perhaps it is a syntax thing? My understanding is that the changes should be instantaneous.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your shown attempts, could you please try following. Please make sure that your index.html, consutuctions.html and .htaccess rules files are present in root folder. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

##Block access to index.html here..
RewriteRule ^index\.html/?$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://www.example.org/$1 [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.34\.567\.891
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/construction\.html/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /construction.html [R=302,L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.org/construction.html
```